# Concentration inequalities for product of gaussians

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, concentration-of-measure

Are there any concentration inequalities (i.e. probability bounds on how a random variable deviates from its expectation) for the product of $n$ independent gaussian random variables with zero means and equal variances? What about different means and variances?

Comment: do you assume the independence of gaussians or no?

Comment: @pointguard0 yes

Answer (score -1):

This [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.10516.pdf) computes the desired probability explicitly in Theorem 3 (page 4).

The theorem states that for independent standard normal Gaussians random variables $g_i$ one has 
$$
\mathbb{P}(X \le t) = \mathbb{P}(X \ge -t) = f_{0.5, 1}\bigg(\frac{2^n} t\bigg),
$$
where 
$$
f_{\nu, \xi}(u) = \nu + \frac 1 {2^{\xi}} \cdot \frac 1 {\pi^{n/2}} \sum_{k=0}^\infty u^{-0.5 - k} \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} H_{kj} \cdot [\log u]^j,
$$
for details and definition of $H_{kj}$ see the paper itself.

The expression seems to be complicate enough to argue to the concentration bound immediately from here, but I believe this is a good starting point.